# Hard copy photos to image files using Files iphone app?

Tags: iphone, photos, scanning, files.app

I have a large collection of old family photos (1000s of them). I need to get these into individual image files for a portrait project.

I have an iphone and a mac, nothing else available to me.

I found that I can use the Files app to scan individual photos in a fairly efficient manner. The problem is that it only allows you to export it into one giant PDF file.

So then I am stuck with finding a way to extract each image individually from the PDF file which will take an extremely long time.

I feel that there is an alternative strategy I can follow that will allow me to avoid having to manually create each image file (i.e. by copy and pasting it from the PDF file).

I know that the Files iphone app scanning step is a manual step, but that is not really avoidable, and it is very fast. The app automatically crops and captures the photo allowing me to scan them very fast. The problem is just going from that step to individual image files.

Comment: An iPhone is not the tool for this.  You need a scanner with a feed that can do at least 600dpi resolution. They aren’t expensive and will be the right tool for the job

Comment: yes but that is the constraints of the question , using something else is out of scope. i can't afford other tools or a service

Comment: even if i could lets answer the question at hand

Comment: Use the regular camera app instead. It takes photos after all

Comment: true that is one option, but that would slow it down immensely -- the files app automatically focuses, crops, and snaps the photo, with no user input required, allowing me to go from one photo to the next without touching my phone at all. this is huge for efficiency.

Comment: It creates documents, not Photos

Comment: I get why you find it more efficient (faster). You might get better quality with the Camera app, but using Files is very quick. If you are happy with the quality, see my answer.

Comment: @Allan Yes, it creates documents, but the documents (PDFs) are just a container for the photos.

Comment: @Gilby,  PDFs are note often than not set to a low resolution suitable for printing - 72dpi.  It’s *not* a container for images as you say, that is just incorrect.

Comment: Microsoft has a scanner tool (free) that will “scan” photos.  Give that a shot.

Comment: @Allan Sorry, but a PDF is a container for all sort of things - and one of those things is images. And, dpi is irrelevant when wanting photos. The PDF's dpi is around 72 dpi, but for my test, the PDF's "page size" is about 81x56 cm and the pixels (which is the important thing) are 2700x1900. I grant you that is not as high as my iPhone camera can do (4000x3000 pixels). But if the OP is happy with the quality, then this is a valid way of quickly scanning photos. Like you, I would use something with better resolution and quality, but for old photos Files may be good enough with decent lighting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [File Juicer](https://echoone.com/filejuicer/)

File Juicer is a general purpose utility which extracts objects from PDFs (and other container formats).  Just open your PDF with File Juicer and in moments you will have a folder alongside the PDF which includes all your images as both JPG and TIFF.

You will need to pay for it (around $20 in the the US) - the trial adds a watermark to any images. I paid 10? years ago and have never had to pay for an upgrade.

Comment: what an apt name

Comment: i finished my project using this, worked perfectly, 20$ well spent

Comment: Glad it worked for you.